# Children IDs not working after using appendTo another element

Tags: jquery

I have an element which I am moving inside another element like so:

```
<div id="parent">    
  <div id="myelem">
      <div id="childelem">
        content
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is simply:

```
$('#myelem').appendTo('#appendhere');
$('#parent #myelem').remove();
```

However, the `#childelem` is not recognized.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: MY BAD. I was also using BXSLIDER with my script and was using infiniteLoop option, which created multiple instances of the element I was trying to append elsewhere. Had nothing to do with appendto. Sorry for any inconvenience!

Comment: well this is what I am doing, I am selecting the #myelem element to put it to the #appendhere elemenet

Comment: to remove the original element; reviewing the answer below I see that appending to ($('#appendhere')) though doesn't clone but moves the element.

Answer (score 1):

api.jquery.com/appendTo

I think youre looking for something more like:

Their example:

```
$( "h2" ).appendTo( $( ".container" ) );
```

This is you:

```
$('#myelem').appendTo($('#appendhere'));
```

EDIT:

So this is working:
(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67ya7/)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <h2>parent</h2>
  <div id="myelem">
      <div id="childelem">
        content
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="appendhere">
  <h2>appendhere</h2>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#myelem').appendTo($('#appendhere'));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you throw an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: It's a lot of custom code I have to input for jsfiddle; I was hoping it would be a lot easier than this. I have to spend like an hour to sort my code out - contains bootstrap, bxslider, etc. What I am trying to do is append an external element inside the modal. However buttons with ids are not working and I have no idea how to test if there's another element with the same id

Comment: What is your $('#appendhere')

Comment: It's a child element inside a bootstrap modal

Comment: I have the exact thing in my code. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I even copy/pasted and changed to the correct names. Nothing. Is there a way I can check for duplicate ids? In either Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: should be able to just do $('#id').length in your console... also check to make sure your jquery library is loading... I had some trouble in my example, I think one of their repos is down if you're using an external source

Comment: (Also you shouldn't need the remove function if you are using the appendTo, only if you were to use append)

Comment: Not `$('#id').length` but `$('[id=id]').length`

Comment: damn I am going to kill myself, I had duplicate IDs because of bxslider's infiniteloop option. It created multiple instances of the same element. :/

Comment: haha.. those smalle bs errors that take forever to figure out :-D